# how to install PNGOUT compression in ubuntu12.04

Tags: php, image-compression

I am trying PNGOUT compression for compressing the PNG images but have been unable to find any information regarding that. Is there any way to get PNGOUT working on Ubuntu12.04 through command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install pngout by installing the binary .
Currently there isn't any deb file for debian/ubuntu as far as i know

Download the binaries [from here](http://www.jonof.id.au/kenutils) and install it.

If you don't know how to install it from binary, [check this resource on ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)

For other optimisation methods you can check out [toy/image_optim](https://github.com/toy/image_optim)

Comment: It was really helpful Thanks, for binary installation i followed the post :[installing binary in Ubuntu] [1]                                                                                                                                [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/643376/how-to-install-exe-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: i'm glad you found it useful. have fun !

Comment: does image_optim provides better optimization and compression than pngout tool, Since it's a combination of all the best tools out there for image compression

Comment: As far as i know image_optim is just "an interface" for different optimisation methods . You choose which one, it doesn't run all of them at once. Again, i'm not sure

Comment: yeah i tried Image_optim they are using all the image compression tool similar to Yahoo Smush it  and its basically built and supported for Mac